# Dual home apache

Tags: linux-networking, httpd

I have RHEL 7.2 server with two NICs on different internal networks. I want the same website available on both network. My site loads from eth0 but not eth1. My httpd.conf has `Listen 80` which I thought would allow it to listen on both interfaces.

```
netstat -pnave
tcp  0  0 0.0.0.0:80  0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 19233433 29479/httpd
```

From httpd.conf

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
  Require all granted
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Apache 2.4.6

Answer (score 2):

Doh! I launched my browser from a machine that only had access to one of the two networks. No surprise it didn't work.